# How to convert SQL to DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have the following DAX statement but i have no idea how to convert it into a DAX query.

```
Si([Ticket State]="12. Cerrado / Closed"; 
NingúnFiltro(Máx([Fecha de Ajuste Final] 
En ([Ticket Id];[Create Time Note]))  En ([Ticket Id]);Todos);"")
```

I know that is in spanish, so, if = si and en = in .

Thank you in advance

Comment: the Table name is Todos? Create time note, what is it?

Comment: I recommend translating your code example and stating i have no idea may be honest but it doesn't truly comply with showing what you have tried, plus what you are showing is not SQL so the title is misleading